# Hive cli starting throws error Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 1.0.4

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am facing below issue to start Hive/beeline :

```
*Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/mine/work/apache-hive-2.3.6-bin/lib/hive-common-2.3.6.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 1.0.4  
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopShims(ShimLoader.java:91)*
```

i followed below url to set up hive setup:
https://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Hive_Install_On_Ubuntu_16_04.php

previously, i had hadoop 1.2.1. now installed 2.7.3.

```
bashrc contains:
mine@ubuntu:~$ echo $HADOOP_HOME 
/home/mine/work/hadoop-2.7.3
mine@ubuntu:~$ echo $HIVE_HOME 
/home/mine/work/apache-hive-2.3.6-bin

hive-env.sh contains:
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/mine/work/hadoop-2.7.3
```

Derby server started.

I am not understanding where hadoop 1.0.4 comes. Is there any compatible issue.

Kindly, Please help me with ur Valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you set your $HADOOP_VERSION ?

Comment: Have you completely removed old Hadoop and rebooted machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try :  export HADOOP_VERSION="2.7.3"